# What's the easiest way to find the version of Windows on a PC?

Tags: windows, version

The title says it all: what's the easiest way to find what version of Windows is installed on a PC?
I often find myself trying to help people with various issues on their computers, and the first question I ask is "what Windows do you have?". Most of them don't know how to answer, so I'd like to find out what's the easiest way to find out. Thank you!

Comment: Start > Run > type "winver" > hit Enter

Comment: Interestingly, though it may be a dupe, not one of those answers gives the 2 easiest ways :/

Comment: Press the Windows + Pause/Break keys on your keyboard. It takes you to the System window, where you see the version of Windows that you have.

Comment: @Tetsujin swapped the dupe, now the top one is better.

Answer (score 0):

- Click Start, type `winver`, hit Enter.

2nd quickest, in case someone can't manage to find Start, or has modified the default Search structure -

- Hit Windows key + R, type `winver`, hit Enter.